# how to send a get request with params without ajax

Tags: jquery

I want to send an ordinary get request which replaces the entire page just like an ordinary get request but using jQuery if possible. I also need to send 2 parameters in the request.

I don't want to replace some content in my document with the result, the result is the complete document.

The code here still sent an ajax request and my page was not refreshed with the response..

```
$.get({
       url: '/swap_games', 
       data: { source: sourceElem, target: targetElem } 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has a `load()` method that does this for you.

```
.load( url, [data,] [complete(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest)] )
```

Example as follows:

```
$('html').load('/swap_games', data: { source: sourceElem, target: targetElem } );
```

Or with a callback:

```
$('html').load('/swap_games', data: { source: sourceElem, target: targetElem }, function() {
   alert('load complete callback');
});
```

More info [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Yes, actually it will. Look at the example, it's in plain site. Plus, I provided a link to the jquery resource which also shows how to pass data with `load()`.

Comment: It fired off the get request but didn't replace my page at all, the original place remained in place. This still looks like it wants to replace content WITHIN a page with the result?

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get({
       url: '/swap_games', 
       data: { source: sourceElem, target: targetElem } 
       success: function( data ){ 
          $('html').html( data ); 
       })
});
```

Comment: This still requires replacing content within my page but i want to replace the entire document with the result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in a third function parameter which replaces the content.

```
$.get('/swap_games', { source: sourceElem, target: targetElem }, function(data) {
        $('html').replaceWith(data);
})
```

Comment: I can't get the syntax right. My complete original js functions is

Comment: I don't want to replace any part of my page content with the result. The result will be a full document and I want it to load as a normal get request.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation points to comment on the accepted answer, but it should be noted that the load() method performs a POST request when the data is supplied as an object, as it is in the example of the accepted answer. If a string is supplied, a GET request is performed.

It should also be noted that both the load() and $.get() methods are asynchronous and probably not needed for your case. What you were probably looking for is

```
window.location.href = "http://your_url_with_any_query_parameters";
```

No jquery needed.

Comment: This may work with ordinary parameters but won't pass array lists.