# Get request headers from index.html page

Tags: javascript, html, http, header

Is there a way I can get request http headers from my index.html page in a JS script?

Meaning not using AJAX.

Comment: If u use Jquery see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7694619/how-to-send-a-get-request-with-params-without-ajax

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)